# Is there any real benefit to padding instructions

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, padding

Knowing that Intel and AMD processors fetch instructions in their native word length (64-bit mainly nowadays), I asked my brother about it and he said that to get the processor to run more efficiently, some assembly programmers pad their instructions to 32 bits with `nop`s if the next instruction will put the byte length at more than 4 or 8 bytes:

```
xor ax, ax ; 2 bytes
nop ; 1
nop ; 1
```

So is there any benefit to doing this?

Comment: On a 386 processor? maybe.  Today? doubtful.

Comment: The fetch size is 16 or 32 bytes these days. There is some benefit to padding in some cases, the case most related to this one is when you have 7 instructions in a 16-byte block on a Core2 (the predecoders would leave the 7th instruction for the next cycle, and only one instruction would be predecoded in that next cycle). Padding with `nop`s would not help in that case, you should pad with prefixes.

Comment: I don't recall that being anything we ever did on the 386.  Can't recall how big the prefetch queue was, but just can't remember there ever being a situation where padding helped anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can substantially increase performance on AMD Bulldozer and Intel Atom, and, to a lesser degree, on Intel Core 2 & Nehalem. For Bulldozer and Core 2 align on 16-byte boundary, for Atom on 8-byte boundary. However, it is preferably to use additional prefixes or longer instruction forms instead of NOPs. Note that aligning instructions only makes sense if you need more than half of peak IPC.

Comment: You are saying alignment matters other than at the target of a control flow change?  The OP's example was for straight-through code.

Comment: Yes, e.g. here is excerpt from Intel optimization manual (about Atom optimizations): "Instruction lengths and alignment can impact decode throughput. The prefetching buffers inside the front end imposes a throughput limit that if the number of bytes being decoded in any 7-cycle window exceeds 48 bytes, the front end will experience a delay to wait for a buffer. Additionally, every time an instruction pair crosses 16 byte boundary, it requires the front end buffer to be held on for at least one more cycle. So instruction alignment crossing 16 byte boundary is highly problematic."

Comment: Nice find!  This text is specifically for Atom, but it makes sense.  I do not see such strong statements in the "Optimizing the Front End" section as applies to Intel's other cores.

Comment: Have a look an Agner Fog's microarchitecture descriptions for details on other microarchitectures.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason for the nop instructions in your example.  Generally, the only use for instruction alignment is to maximize the number of instructions fetched at the target of a control flow branch, e.g. a function call.  Modern x86 fetch and decode units are well optimized for the variable length nature of x86 encoding.  Padding like this only slows things down.

A scan of the Intel Volume 4 optimization manual (maybe a few years out-of-date) provided no reasons for instruction padding.